# Python create acronym from first characters of each word and include the numbers

Tags: python, regex, element, capture

I have a string as follows: 
`theatre = 'Regal Crown Center Stadium 14'`

I would like to break this into an acronym based on the first letter in each word but also include both numbers:
desired output = `'RCCS14'`

My code attempts below:
`acronym = "".join(word[0] for word in theatre.lower().split())
 acronym = "".join(word[0].lower() for word in re.findall("(\w+)", theatre))
 acronym = "".join(word[0].lower() for word in re.findall("(\w+ | \d{1,2})", theatre))
 acronym = re.search(r"\b(\w+ | \d{1,2})", theatre)`

In which I wind up with something like: `rccs1` but can't seem to capture that last number. There could be instances when the number is in the middle of the name as well: `'Regal Crown Center 14 Stadium'` as well. TIA!

Comment: Is there a possibility for multiple uppercase letters in a row, such as `AMC Loews Uptown 1`? What's the desired output? Same goes for `IMAX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/rNDktx/2)

```
(?:(?<=\s)|^)(?:[a-z]|\d+)
```

- `(?:(?<=\s)|^)` Ensure what precedes is either a space or the start of the line
- `(?:[a-z]|\d+)` Match either a single letter or one or more digits

The `i` flag (`re.I` in python) allows `[a-z]` to match its uppercase variants.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##FYs9C8IwFAD3/IpHl@ShBkQnsXTo5KqjVQgm2ki@eImI0v8e63Qc3KVPGWPY1Gp9ilSADGME7Ux5iz5ZZwQ1otuJbt8OGacrznJWq@9lGvQCm@W/PCDL88OP5qEc9BTfAXoTiiE4FaXty8N6yxlLZEMRnMtntEGQvNuglXMiIyKr9Qc)

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"(?:(?<=\s)|^)(?:[a-z]|\d+)", re.I)
s = 'Regal Crown Center Stadium 14'

print(''.join(r.findall(s)))
```

The code above finds all instances where the regex matches and joins the list items into a single string.

Result: `RCCS14`

Comment: Updated the accepted answer as I finally put all this together and I found corner cases where this what much more robust!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub()` to remove all lowercase letters and spaces.

**Regex**: [`[a-z ]+`](https://regex101.com/r/wev2VQ/1)

Details:

- `[]+` Match a single character present in the list between one and
  unlimited times

**Python code**:

```
re.sub(r'[a-z ]+', '', theatre)
```

Output: `RCCS14`

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/eCkgmv)

Comment: Elegant solution with a simple explanation! I tip my hat to you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment since I don't have enough reputation, but *S. Jovan* answer isn't satisfying since it assumes that each word starts with a capital letter and that each word has one and only one capital letter.

```
re.sub(r'[a-z ]+', '', "Regal Crown Center Stadium YB FIEUBFB DBUUFG FUEH  14")
```

will returns `'RCCSYBFIEUBFBDBUUFGFUEH14'`

However *ctwheels* answers will be able to work in this case :

```
r = re.compile(r"\b(?:[a-z]|\d+)", re.I)
s = 'Regal Crown Center Stadium YB FIEUBFB DBUUFG FUEH  14'

print(''.join(r.findall(s)))
```

will print

```
RCCSYFDF14
```

Comment: Usually, you would just link to the answer on the same page. I've since changed my answer since it's more effective against things like `'` or `-` that may be present in words. Linking to existing answers ensures you're always using the most updated version :) If an answer is outside of StackOverflow then you can copy the contents.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, feel free to add my remark into your answer, and I will delete my post :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
theatre = 'Regal Crown Center Stadium 14'
r = re.findall("\s(\d+|\S)", ' '+theatre)
print(''.join(r))
```

Gives me `RCCS14`